# Checking correctness of "If you ever do say like that......"

Tags: conditional-constructions

Can I say the following sentence to a person I'm angry with? I heard this when I was watching "13 Reasons Why":

> If you ever do say like that to your mother, I will kill you.

I'm an Indian, and I've been learning English watching American shows and they speak too fast, eating some words so I may not have heard it correctly.

I know that the following is acceptable and correct

> I do say like that.

So, considering the above statement, I think it's correct. But I'm not sure. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You should provide more context in your question. Perhaps it can be reopened. Also, please consider reworking your example. Surely you can come up with something that doesn't advocate murder.

Comment: In the future, all this information belongs in your question, when you ask your question, not in the comments after it gets closed. Please read our [_Details, Please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I wasn't trying to close the question permanently, but I wanted to exhort the OP to provide more context.

Comment: In that particular context ("{verb} like that"), we would choose the verb **speak** or **talk**, not the verb **say**.

Comment: I've edited your question to show you an example of the kind of detail that we need to write answers that are more likely to help you (and other folks that might have the same sort of question!). Feel free to adjust what I've written into your own words.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence:

> I do say like that.

is missing a direct object (**what** do you say like that?). This would be acceptable to my native-English ears:

> I do say *it* like that.

The sentence you asked about has much the same problem. This sounds natural to me:

> If you ever do say *that* like that to your mother, I will kill you.

Where *that* refers to the thing you might say to your mother.